# Objective C For loops with @autorelease and ARC

Tags: core-data, automatic-ref-counting, autorelease

As part of an app that allows auditors to create findings and associate photos to them (Saved as Base64 strings due to a limitation on the web service) I have to loop through all findings and their photos within an audit and set their sync value to true.

Whilst I perform this loop I see a memory spike jumping from around 40MB up to 500MB (for roughly 350 photos and 255 findings) and this number never goes down. On average our users are creating around 1000 findings and 500-700 photos before attempting to use this feature. I have attempted to use @autorelease pools to keep the memory down but it never seems to get released.

```
    for (Finding * __autoreleasing f in self.audit.findings){
        @autoreleasepool {
            [f setToSync:@YES];
            NSLog(@"%@", f.idFinding);

        for (FindingPhoto * __autoreleasing p in f.photos){
            @autoreleasepool {
                [p setToSync:@YES];
                p = nil;
            }

        }
        f = nil;

        }
    }
```

The relationships and retain cycles look like this

Audit has a strong reference to Finding

Finding has a weak reference to Audit and a strong reference to FindingPhoto

FindingPhoto has a weak reference to Finding

What am I missing in terms of being able to effectively loop through these objects and set their properties without causing such a huge spike in memory. I'm assuming it's got something to do with so many Base64 strings being loaded into memory when looping through but never being released.

Comment: How are these objects stored and loaded? They won't be autoreleased because they're still retained by the arrays you're iterating over...

Comment: Stored in core data and loaded using NSFetchRequests into a MutableArray. Is there a better way of loading these to only load and release one at a time as it's causing the app to crash if there are too many.

Comment: I should mention that the only FetchRequest that is performed is the one on the Audit object, the rest are accessed through their relationships an not loaded explicitly.

Comment: How about storing photos as external files and making the core data entity provide a reference to one of those files (path, URL...)?  That way, loading a core data relationship would have a small footprint and you could explicitly control how many photos were in memory.

Comment: @PhillipMills is this as simple as marking that Base64 property in core data as 'Store in External Record File' or will I have to go the whole hog and actual write to files an store or generate the path to the file when reading the image back?

Comment: You may need to experiment.  My first thought is that, if it's tied to core data directly, you won't have control of the loading...but I could easily be wrong about that.

Comment: There is no point to making local variables `__autoreleasing`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first, make sure you have a batch size set on the fetch request. Choose a relatively small number, but not too small because this isn't for UI processing. You want to batch a reasonable number of objects into memory to reduce loading overhead while keeping memory usage down. Try 50 or 100 and see how it goes, then consider upping the batch size a little.

If all of the objects you're loading are managed objects then the correct way to evict them during processing is to turn them into faults. That's done by calling `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` on the context. BUT - that discards any changes, and your loop is specifically there to make changes.

So, what you should really be doing is batch saving the objects you've modified and then turning those objects back into faults to remove the data from memory.

So, in your loop, keep a counter of how many you've modified and save the context each time you hit that count and refresh all the objects that were processed so far. The batch on the fetch and the batch size to save should be the same number.

Comment: Thank you so much for this suggestion. I've done as you said and the memory usage during this operation has dropped by about 75% without any need to restructure my data or store it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a big difference in size between your "Finding" objects and the associated images. So your primary aim should be to redesign your database in a way so that unfaulting (loading) a `Finding` object does not automatically load the base64 encoded image.

That's actually one of the major strengths of Code Data: Loading part of an object hierarchy. Just try to move the base64 encoded data to an own (managed) object so that Core Data does not load it. It will still be loaded as needed when the reference is touched.